# Internal case class in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I have the following case class

```
case class MyClass (LeftHandSide: (Set[String], String), RightHandSide: Double)
```

so, I can do the following

```
MyClass((Set("yu", "ye"), "bee"), 0.03).filter( x=> x.RightHandSide>4)
```

and I would like to able to call parts of the LeftHandSide by name too, e.g:

```
case class MyClass (LeftHandSide: (Part1: Set[String], Part2: String), RightHandSide: Double)
```

And then:

```
MyClass((Set("yu", "ye"), "bee"), 0.03).filter(x => x.LeftHandSide.Part2 != "bee")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I cannot create such a class: case class MyClass (LeftHandSide: (Part1: Set[String], Part2: String), RightHandSide: Double)

Comment: Is this line compiling in your program? Its giving an error in the repl. filter method is only applicable on collections.                                 MyClass((Set("yu", "ye"), "bee"), 0.03).filter( x=> x.RightHandSide>4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an additional case class called `LeftHandSide`:

```
case class LeftHandSide(partOne: Set[String], partTwo: String)
```

And use that in `MyClass`:

```
case class MyClass(leftHandSide: LeftHandSide, rightHandSide: Double)
```

And then:

```
val myClass = MyClass(LeftHandSide(Set("yu", "ye"), "bee"), 0.03)
myClass.leftHandSide.partTwo != "bee"
```